# Is there any method for labeling without iteration with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two time-based data. One is the accelerometer's measurement data, another is label data.
For example,

accelerometer.csv

```
timestamp,X,Y,Z
1.0,0.5,0.2,0.0
1.1,0.2,0.3,0.0
1.2,-0.1,0.5,0.0
...
2.0,0.9,0.8,0.5
2.1,0.4,0.1,0.0
2.2,0.3,0.2,0.3
...
```

label.csv

```
start,end,label
1.0,2.0,"running"
2.0,3.0,"exercising"
```

Maybe these data are unrealistic because these are just examples.

In this case, I want to merge these data to below:
merged.csv

```
timestamp,X,Y,Z,label
1.0,0.5,0.2,0.0,"running"
1.1,0.2,0.3,0.0,"running"
1.2,-0.1,0.5,0.0,"running"
...
2.0,0.9,0.8,0.5,"exercising"
2.1,0.4,0.1,0.0,"exercising"
2.2,0.3,0.2,0.3,"exercising"
...
```

I'm using the "iterrows" of pandas. However, the number of rows of real data is greater than 10,000. Therefore, the running time of program is so long. I think, there is at least one method for this work without iteration.

My code like to below:

```
import pandas as pd

acc = pd.read_csv("./accelerometer.csv")
labeled = pd.read_csv("./label.csv")

for index, row in labeled.iterrows():
    start = row["start"]
    end = row["end"]

    acc.loc[(start <= acc["timestamp"]) & (acc["timestamp"] < end), "label"] = row["label"]
```

How can I modify my code to get rid of "for" iteration?

Comment: what is the maximum resolution of your timestamp variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the times in `accelerometer` don't go outside the boundaries of the times in `label`, you could use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```py
accmerged = pd.merge_asof(acc, labeled, left_on='timestamp', right_on='start', direction='backward')
```

Output (for the sample data in your question):

```
   timestamp    X    Y    Z  start  end       label
0        1.0  0.5  0.2  0.0    1.0  2.0     running
1        1.1  0.2  0.3  0.0    1.0  2.0     running
2        1.2 -0.1  0.5  0.0    1.0  2.0     running
3        2.0  0.9  0.8  0.5    2.0  3.0  exercising
4        2.1  0.4  0.1  0.0    2.0  3.0  exercising
5        2.2  0.3  0.2  0.3    2.0  3.0  exercising
```

Note you can remove the `start` and `end` columns with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) if you want to:

```py
accmerged = accmerged.drop(['start', 'end'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   timestamp    X    Y    Z       label
0        1.0  0.5  0.2  0.0     running
1        1.1  0.2  0.3  0.0     running
2        1.2 -0.1  0.5  0.0     running
3        2.0  0.9  0.8  0.5  exercising
4        2.1  0.4  0.1  0.0  exercising
5        2.2  0.3  0.2  0.3  exercising
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly I wanted solution! Thank you again!